# как обозначаются массивы и прочие структуры данных на блок-схемах алгоритмов?

Tags: алгоритм, блок-схема

В ГОСТе 19.701-90 об этом вообще ничего не говорится.
Где-то читал, что на блок-схемах нельзя использовать синтаксические средства конкретного языка программирования.

Использовать математические обозначения, в виде множеств? Идея не плохая, но в математике тоже, не все так однозначно получается и легко "утонуть" в деталях. Упорядоченные множества, неупорядоченные множества. Вся эта <s>поебистика</s> с парадоксами и множеством мнений на один и тот же вопрос.

Вроде как, язык математики изначально создавался для максимально точного описания абстрактных понятий. Но на практике всё получается настолько расплывчато, что даже естественный язык, иногда дает ему фору во многих отношениях.

Comment: Блок-схема — вещь довольно абстрактная... то что писать в блоках ни как не специализировано... Можно использовать математические обозначения с индексами вида A_i, можно и обычные вида A[i].

Comment: @Fat-Zer спасибо